# The better approach to design AngularJS services

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm writing an AngularJS client application that would interact with a REST server.

To manage the client / server interaction I'm using the [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) abstraction.
Actually I'm writing every resource as a separated [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) and injecting it only in the controllers that are gonna use it.

I've started to develop using the [angularjs-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), so in my separed `services.js` file I've got an increasing number of services:

```
angular.module('testReqService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('TestReq', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://test-url.com/api/test', {}, {});
});
angular.module('registerService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Register', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://test-url.com/api/user/new', {}, {});
});
//More services here...
```

Everything works fine, but I'm wondering if this is the best approach.

So, is better to write separate services for different `REST` requests and inject them only in the controllers that need it, or a better approach is to write a single service with different methods and URL for every request?

Comment: I typically write a single service with a subset of related functions. That's just me tho, either way, I'm intrigued with this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer the second approach:

```
var resources = angular.module("myapp.resources", ['ngResource']);

resources.factory('Constants', [
    function() {
        return {
            RESOURCE_URL: "http://www.example.com/rest"
        }
    }
]);

resources.factory('Rest', ['Constants', '$resource', function(C, $resource) {
    return {
        Users: $resource(C.RESOURCE_URL + '/users/:id', {
            id: '@id',
        }, {})
        , Posts: $resource(C.RESOURCE_URL + '/posts/:user', {
              user: '@'
        }, {})
    }
}]);
```

When you have several resources, become very annoying to manage all the dependencies in your controller. That way, all you have to do is inject a single one. It is also, in my opinion, easier to understand when reading the controller:

```
$scope.user = Rest.Users.get({id: 1});
```

is more understandable that

```
$scope.user = Users.get({id: 1});
```

Comment: I like this approach as well, much easier to read, especially when you starting adding more and more.

Comment: I like this approach too. I think I'm gonna use a mixed approach, trying to merge all the related resources in the same service.