# What is the right way to pass the same web address to all my controllers in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I have a bunch of controllers which are performing CRUD operations. These controllers all are making request to the same base URL, what is the right way to pass this URL to each controller without rewriting it everywhere or just making some global? Since I am new to to Angular I was wondering if there was some built in facility in $http that already does this and I just need to set that value.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896535/the-better-approach-to-design-angularjs-services/18896885#18896885)

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is you don't have to perform your CRUD operations in a controller.
CRUD is a job for the Model part of MVC.

First, you can use Constant :

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.constant('ENV_URL','https://test.com');
```

And you can inject and call this constant where you need it.

Next, your CRUD have to be placed in a factory like this :

```
  angular.module('myApp').factory('usersFact',function ($resource,ENV_URL)
          {
    var User = $resource(ENV_URL, { userId: '@id' }, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false,
            headers: { 'Accept': 'what you need' }
        },post : {}, put :{}


        }
    });

    return {
        getSummary : function (id, cb) {
            var summary = User.getSummary({ userId: id },
                function () {
                    console.log(summary);
                    });

            return summary;
        }
    };
}
```

);

And, in your controller your can now use your data :

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('ProfilCtrl',
function ($scope,usersFact,) {
    $scope.userInfo = usersFact.getSummary(userId, function () {
        console.log($scope.userInfo)
    });
```

}
);

Answer (score -1):

Well I guess you should create a service and do the heavy-lifting there and expose methods that the controllers could call.

Answer (score -1):

There are Two ways to do this...

The first method is by $rootscope. The $rootscope is the parent of all $scopes in all controllers so any property you assign to $rootscope will be accessible by any $scope.

By running the below code you can then access "http://myurl.com" in any controller using $scope.url

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.url = "http://myurl.com";
});
```

The other way is to use a service/factory like this...

```
app.factory('globalurl', function() {
    return "http://myurl.com";
});
```

then write all your controllers like this...

```
function Ctrl1($scope, globalurl) {
    $scope.url = globalurl(); 
}
```