# AngularJS REST service calls

Tags: angularjs, rest

I'm looking to add factory/service calls for the URLs below to an AngularJS project in a way that follows the DRY principle. The project uses `ngResource`.

```
http://localhost/vehicles/{type:car|truck}/drive/{2wd|4wd}?sort={"start":"1", "limit':"10", "sortBy": "make"}
http://localhost/vehicles/{type:car|truck}/drive/{2wd|4wd}/count
http://localhost/vehicles/bestselling/{type:car|truck}?sort={"start":"1", "limit':"10", "sortBy": "make"}
http://localhost/vehicles/bestselling/{type:car|truck}/count
```

- All calls are HTTP GET
- The URL path parameters `"{type:car|truck}`" can be either one of `"car"` or `"truck"` the same goes for `"{2wd|4wd}"`.
- The URLs ending with count return the number of items (for pagination); the rest return the list of items to be displayed.

How can I define the factory/service calls for these resources in Angular? I have not had any luck finding an answer for this; the closest I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896535/the-better-approach-to-design-angularjs-services)

Disclaimer: I have no experience with AngularJS

Comment: Can you share your vehicles resource schema

Comment: Have you looked into using `$resource`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource You have some complicated needs, but they are all possible and made easy with `$resource`

Comment: I (re-)read the $resource page as Joao suggested and combined the examples in the document with the solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896535/the-better-approach-to-design-angularjs-services) to find a solution to my issue. I don't know if its the best solution but it works! Answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

services.js

```
resources.factory('Constants', [
function() {
    return {
        RESOURCE_URL: "http://localhost/vehicles"
    }
}
]);

resources.factory('Rest', ['Constants', '$resource', function(C, $resource) {
return {
    BestSellingCount: $resource(C.RESOURCE_URL + '/bestselling/:type/count', {
        type: '@type'},{})
    BestSelling: $resource(C.RESOURCE_URL + '/bestselling/:type', {
          type: '@type'}, {
          getBestSelling: { method:'GET', params: {sort: {"start":"1", "limit':"10", "sortBy": "make"}}, isArray: true)}}})
}]);
```

And in my controller

```
$scope.bestsellingtrucks = Rest.BestSelling.getBestSelling({type:"truck"});
```

The default sort and pagination values get passed in as a query string